# Query contacts across multiple mailboxes in 1 service call

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way, using Exchange Web Services Managed API, to query for a contact across multiple mailboxes using a single service call?  I have a grid that loads contacts for the current user but as one of the grid columns I want to show a list of all other users who have that same contact (matching by contact email address for example).

I've found this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/8b85d22f-cf0d-4771-a0b9-f4e98206a61a) and this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/6b64a2ca-4ee8-40d1-9e35-68faa9664cd4) on how to do it using an older version of EWS but I haven't been able to implement it with the current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS supports this as told in the post. Is it possible that you are using the EWS Managed API? This API unfortunately does not have a FindItems method which takes multiple foler ids. You'll need to use EWS directly for this.

Comment: Have you noticed a considerable improvement in using EWS directly to this in one call versus using the managed api and multiple calls?

Comment: You certainly have fewer roundtrips, but I have not done any performance measurement on this.

Comment: Thanks!  This made a decent impact for me from about a 5-6 second load  , using the managed api and multiple calls, to about 2-3 second load on one of my web sites which calls a WCF service that accesses the EWS.